# Why my betta lounges at water surface repeatedly

Tags: behavior, betta, swimming

I have a no-filter small tank where I keep my betta. There is a small pothos inside, as a way to absorb all the urea. But just today I realized he keeps on lounging towards the surface till his snout and eyes break the water surface. He does this repeatedly about 4-5 times, then stops and swims normally. I took him out and put him in a new dechlorinated water, just in case, with air bubbles.

Do you have any idea why he is doing this? Is it normal or a bad sign?

Comment: what is the readings of your latest watertest PH-AMMONIA-NITRITE_NITRATE please edit the readings into your question,and please get a proper tank with filter and all.please take a look here https://modestfish.com/how-to-cycle-your-aquarium/

Comment: A good question about Betta fish that we didn't already have!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bettas are [anabantoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anabantoidei), commonly known as labyrinth fish after the labyrinth organ, which is a kind of lung-like extension of the gill tissue which can absorb oxygen from air.

For labyrinth fish, occasional surface gulping is quite normal and is a supplementary breathing action. This doesn't mean the fish isn't suffering from ammonia, nitrite or chlorine poisoning as you would generally assume from other fish families, but it is not a smoking gun in this case.

Still, it would be prudent to get a test kit for ammonia and nitrite, and consider installing a simple filter.

Comment: Thanks for the information. As I look closer in the tank, it seems some tiny planarias have emerged... so that's a positive on nitrite/ammonia spike. Will install a small filter for him asap. Thanks guys.